# Program restarts when a function returns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made a program which does Pythagoras theorem for you if you just insert the lengths of the sides.

```
from math import *

def pythag(a , b):
    c = sqrt(a^2 + b^2)
    return c

print(pythag(3,4)) # added this as recommended in comment
```

But when I run it, this happens:

```
 RESTART: C:/Users/Andrei/Documents/USB Backup/Python/Ultimate Calculator/functions2.py 
 5.0
```

I'm a noob at python so I don't really see the problem with the code.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Post the actual code and error messages.

Comment: Along with the actual code snippet , you should describe what are the error messages and stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

You've written a function  that does what you say but you're not actually calling it anywhere. The top level statements in your program are an `import` and a `def` and only those are called when you "run" it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the function after the code you already have (e.g. for values 3 and 4):

```
from math import *

def pythag (a, b):
    c = sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
    return c


print(pythag(3,4))
```

Comment: I copied yours and put it into idle, but this happened:      RESTART: C:/Users/Andrei/Documents/USB Backup/Python/Ultimate Calculator/functions2.py 
5.0

Comment: @MCFapster code runs perfectly fine on IDEone: http://ideone.com/2OMBH2
Something else has to be wrong with your code or the way you execute it.

Comment: Actually the code did run for you, in fact the 5.0 at the end of your comment is the result of the code running! @MCFapster

Comment: when I run it using the console, it restarts before it outputs. @chalarangelo

Answer (score 0):

Rather than importing math you could use the power signs.

For example:

```
def pythag(a , b):
    c = (a**2 + b**2)**0.5
    return c

print(pythag(3,4))
```